# Delphi: make unicode RAR-component 2.0

Tags: delphi, unicode, components, ansi, rar

I have [RAR-component 2.0](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=300) and Delphi 2010. This component uses AnsiString for File Path. How can I make it unicode? I changed AnsiString to String in RAR.pas but it did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: If the DLL supports unicode, you should look at the documentation, examples, or source code, on how to make use of it. If the DLL does not already support Unicode, there's nothing you can do from the outside that will make it do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **RAR.pas**:

- Change **TRARArchiveInformation**'s `fFileName` field and the `Filename` property to **WideString**.
- Change `TRAR.OpenFile` so the `FileName` argument is  a **WideString**.
- In `TRAR.OpenArchive(Extract:boolean)` change this line:

  `ArcName := PAnsiChar(fArchiveInformation.FileName);`

  to this:

  `ArcNameW := PWideChar(fArchiveInformation.FileName);`

In **RAR_DLL.pas**:

Change `GetFileModifyDate` so this line:

```
h := OpenFile(PAnsiChar(FileName), Struct, OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE);
```

is this:

```
h := FileOpen(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

and remove the `Struct: TOFSTRUCT;` line from the **var** block.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the sourcecode that you just linked to, I think you didn't have to change anything. It looks like it should already support unicode. The author claims it's for Delphi 2009, I see that there are two versions of TRarProcessFile():

```
TRARProcessFile = function(hArcData: THandle; Operation: Integer; DestPath, DestName: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
TRARProcessFileW = function(hArcData: THandle; Operation: Integer; DestPath, DestName: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

TRARProcessFileW should accept a filename with Unicode characters. 
Did you try to use that?

Maybe it somehow still doesn't work (I haven't tried it myself with Unicode characters yet), but if this doesn't work, then maybe it's helpful if you describe what goes wrong with a bit more detail.

Oh, and just to be sure: you are using Delphi 2009+ right?

Comment: Perhaps it is problem in Rur.dll. I changed all to String and when I open an archive the Demo show me ERAR_EOPEN = 15. May be rur.dll uses AnsiString and I need new one... I do now know.

Comment: And a problem is in function OpenFile(FileName: AnsiString): boolean;

Comment: You should leave the parameter types to PAnsiChar, PChar, or PWideChar, whatever it was before you changed it. Changing it to string won't help as that is a native Delphi-only type, and it is incompatible (at least when doing external calls like this) with P*Char.

Comment: You simply don't need to change anything. Delphi 2009 is the same as 2010 and XE regarding string/Unicode issues.